# Getting a certificate invalid error in UWP application

Tags: uwp, certificate, identityserver4

I'm trying to get the token endpoint from an Identity Server instance.  Currently I have the following code:

```
var disco = await _httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
{
    Address = "https://localhost:5501"                
});
```

If I run this in a console app and output the endpoint:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Endpoint: {disco.TokenEndpoint}");
```

It works fine.  However, if I take the exact same code and run it from a UWP desktop application, I get an error:

```
Error connecting to https://localhost:5501/.well-known/openid-configuration: 
An error occurred while sending the request.
```

Drilling into the inner exception it appears to be a certificate error:

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
```

If I manually navigate to 
    https://localhost:5501/.well-known/openid-configuration
then I can see the document fine.

In the Identity Server, I'm using this:

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error from the UWP application; as I understand it, the certificate authority that it needs is taken care of by the Visual Studio installation.  But what I really can't understand is why it works in a console application but not the desktop app.

Comment: I hadn't done - but doing so makes no difference

Comment: For accessing the localhost, you need to add the above capability.

Comment: Needed "Shared User Certificate" as well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you need to add `EnterpriseAuthentication` `PrivateNetwork` `Shared User Certificates` access capability for your uwp project. For more detail, please refer [app capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) official document.